# How to doc dynamic object properties on apidoc

Tags: javascript, node.js, documentation, api-doc

The thing is that I want to documentate an api response that looks like this:

```
{
    "box": {
        "1": "foo"
        "2": "bar"
    },
}
```

The object has dynamic properties such as numbers.

How can I document these properties?

For example, something like this:

```
/**
 * @api {get} /endpoint
 * @apiSuccess {Object}  box       Object description
 * @apiSuccess {String}  box.?     Property description
 */
```

I am using Node.js just in case.

Answer (score 0):

I would think about what the dynamic properties have in common and describe that. If they have nothing in common besides being properties of "box", I would just mention that.

```
/**
 * @api {get} /endpoint
 * @apiSuccess {Object}  box       Object that includes dynamic properties, that may be numbers.
 */
```